# Ошибка проверки EPP DOMAIN CREATE

Tags: api, dns

Добрался до создания домена через API sidn.nl, до этого прорвался через дубовую техподдержку - HELLO, LOGIN и DOMAIN CHECK уже работают, так что сессия у меня есть и там всё правильно.

Возвращает Command syntax error на этот XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
<command><create>
<domain:create xmlns:domain="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0">
<domain:name>5gmobiel.nl</domain:name><domain:period unit="y">1</domain:period><domain:ns>
<domain:hostObj>ns1.sidn.nl</domain:hostObj></domain:ns>
<domain:ns><domain:hostObj>ns2.sidn.nl</domain:hostObj></domain:ns>
<domain:registrant>FLO015428-AFGLI</domain:registrant>
<domain:contact type="admin">FLO015428-AFGLI</domain:contact>
<domain:contact type="tech">FLO015428-AFGLI</domain:contact>
<domain:authInfo><domain:pw></domain:pw></domain:authInfo>
</domain:create></create>
<extension>
<secDNS:create xmlns:secDNS="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:secDNS-1.1"></secDNS:create></extension>
<clTRID>AFREG-12345</clTRID>
</command></epp>
```

Вот такой результат:

```
<response><result code="2001"><msg>Command syntax error</msg></result><trID><clTRID>AFREG-12345</clTRID><svTRID>SIDN</svTRID></trID></response>
```

XML ессно проверял https://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: Ну в RFC5731 один блок `<domain:ns>` внутри которого N записей hostObj, а у вас каждый хост внутри отдельного NS блока. не знаю, критично ли это, но это единственное отличие от RFC

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за быстрый ответ! Я попробовал изменить как Вы говорите - результат такой же.

Comment: Я кстати выкинул секцию <secDNS:keyData> - у меня нет данных чтобы туда что-то задавать. Может это плохо? По схеме эта секция необязательна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот XML работает:

```
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
<command>
<create>
<domain:create xmlns:domain="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0">
<domain:name>testtest.nl</domain:name>
<domain:period unit="m">12</domain:period>
<domain:ns>
<domain:hostObj>ns1.yourdomain.com</domain:hostObj>
        <domain:hostObj>ns2.yourdomain.com</domain:hostObj>
        </domain:ns>
<domain:registrant>TES093515-X1584</domain:registrant>
<domain:contact type="admin">TES093515-X1584</domain:contact>
    <domain:contact type="tech">TES093515-X1584</domain:contact>
<domain:contact type="billing">TES093515-X1584</domain:contact>
<domain:authInfo>
<domain:pw>qcbJsi68k-;P04QxVTKsU</domain:pw>
</domain:authInfo>
</domain:create>
</create>
<clTRID>1477398822-5wsm4XbVrt</clTRID>
</command>
</epp>
```

Если кто-то когда-то будет работать с sidn.nl - надо рассчитывать только на community, потому что мануалы неактуальные а техподдержка никакая (больше вредит).